# How do I add PDF print functionality to Metabase in Clojure

Tags: pdf, clojure, metabase

I have forked the metabase project and want to add some "export to pdf" functionality into the reports where you can currently export to csv, excel and json.

[image: export options for reports]

I tried finding it and spent a lot of time looking for an existing fork of metabase that might have this functionality but could not find anything.

In src/metabase/util there is a file containing some of the logic for exporting to csv, json, etc. It is called export.clj

so far I have written some edits but I have no experience with Clojure so I'm just trying to wing it so far and then hopefully get some guidance from the SO community.

```
(def export-formats
  "Map of export types to their relevant metadata"
  {
    "pdf"  {:export-fn      export-to-pdf
           :content-type     "application/pdf"
           :ext            "pdf"
           :context     :pdf-download},
    "csv"  {:export-fn    export-to-csv
           :content-type "text/csv"
           :ext          "csv"
           :context      :csv-download},
   "xlsx" {:export-fn    export-to-xlsx
           :content-type "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
           :ext          "xlsx"
           :context      :xlsx-download},
   "json" {:export-fn    export-to-json
           :content-type "applicaton/json"
           :ext          "json"
           :context      :json-download}})
```

Further up in that same page are the definitions of some of these functions referred to. So I added one for pdf which is just the csv function duplicated because I just want to try see that a new option shows first.

```
(defn- export-to-pdf [column-names rows]
  (with-out-str
    ;; turn keywords into strings, otherwise we get colons in our output
    (csv/write-csv *out* (into [(mapv name column-names)] rows))))
```

My metabase clone is installed on Heroku. I tried making the above changes and saw no result in the download option. I tried removing other download methods from this file and also saw no changes.

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction to go about changing this.

Comment: looks like you only found the server-side functions. Search for '.csv' in the client-side code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metabase is an actively maintained project with some great people working full time on it. And adding features is what makes opensource magic. With projects like this it's almost always easier to work with the existing people to add new things.

1. check if just using your browsers print-to-pdf function is good enough.
2. start by checking the github page for open or closed [project issues page](https://github.com/metabase/metabase/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+) about this:
3. Contact the metabase folks (some of whom are likely to see this message) and tell them what you want. Offer your help and ask where the best place to start is.
4. get the metabase development environment setup by following [these instructions](https://github.com/metabase/metabase/blob/master/docs/developers-guide.md)
5. read these instruction and especially the contributing guide. Then open a PR for what you are working on. Don't just call them up with a completed new feature. Communicate early and often.
6. Add your export feature to the backend export section and the frontend page
7. Add UI tests and tests for the backend.
8. Don't sweat it when there are many rounds back and forth to get the PR in a state for being merged. It's not a critisism of you to make the code fit nicely.